# I don’t get the same results with "Java API for Elasticsearch" and "Kibana"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

**Here is what I have:**

I have an index in elasticseach storing thousands of documents. Each document includes a field called 'deviceName'.

**Here is what I would like to do with java api:**

I want to get all devices stored in my index and their occurence (number of time a device appears in this index).

**Here is my java code:**

```
    String[] indexVector = new String[1];
    indexVector[0] = "myIndex";
    String [] values = new String[2];
    values[0] = "sum_delta";
    values[1] = "count_frames";
    String [] totalPercentage = new String[1];
    totalPercentage[0] = "devices>per_percentage";
    SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse) client.prepareSearch(indexVector)
            .setSize(10000)
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("devices").field("deviceName")
                    .size(100)
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_delta").field("delta"))
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("count_frames").field("cnt"))
                    .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketScript("per_percentage")
                            .setBucketsPaths(values)
                            .script(new Script("_value0 / (_value0 + _value1 + 1)"))                
                            )
                    )
            .addAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.avgBucket("avg_per_all_devices")
                    .setBucketsPaths(totalPercentage)
                    )           
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

**How I search in Kibana:**
[image]

**Here is my results:**

With java API I get 63 devices and with kibana 64 devices. However, the biggest problem for me is the occurence. Indeed, for a device that has a occurence lower than 30, i have the same result with Java api and Kibana. But, when the occurence is larger, kibana returns a occurence greater than the one returned by java API. Example: kibana returns 1010 and in the same time java api returns 880.

I really don't understand why there is so much difference.

**Question:**

So, please, can you tell me what is wrong in my code and what I have to do ?

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Comment: Is that your exact copy/pasted code or you typed it? As it is it wouldn't  compile. Please copy/paste your exact Java code. Also can you show the request sent by Kibana?

Comment: I just deleted in my code a part that I thought not relevant for my question. I added a picture to show how I do my researchs in kibana.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because of the setSize parameter. The set size parameter first gets the 10000 documents and then performs aggregation on them while I don't think you are setting such a size in Kibana. Try setting get size to actual doc count and see if ambiguity persists.

Answer (score 0):

I support there be some documents that `_value0 + _value1 + 1` equals 0. You can print the `response.toString()`, I guess there be one shard faild, 880 documents are closed to `four-fifths` of 1010 documents.
You can also view elasticseach's log, it will print `ERROR`.

Comment: _value0=sum_delta and _value1= count_frames. Both are positive so _value0 + _value1 + 1 is always strictly greater than 0.